# Translation Golf XLI - The Pursuit of Happyness

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Game over! Winner: Carlos Arturo Serrano with a [61-char answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26305/13628)!

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This time I picked a dialogue from the movie The Pursuit of Happyness.
I have to say that I absolutely *love* this movie. I think Will Smith is outstanding in it, and it's got some really powerful moments (subway scene...).

Anyways... Here the main character, Chris Gardner, gives his son some [valuable advice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K12jtNR0K9Q):

> —<sup><sub>1</sub></sup>Don't ever let somebody tell you you can't do something. <sup><sub>2</sub></sup>Not even me. Alright?
>   —Alright.
>   —<sup><sub>3</sub></sup>You got a dream, you gotta protect it. <sup><sub>4</sub></sup>People can't do something themselves, they wanna tell you you can't do it. <sup><sub>5</sub></sup>You want something, go get it. Period.
>
> <sub>(183 characters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts (which I conveniently numbered) more or less intact.

My own, non-golfed translation:

> —<sup><sub>1</sub></sup>Nunca permitas que nadie te diga que no puedes hacer una cosa. <sup><sub>2</sub></sup>Ni siquiera yo mismo. ¿De acuerdo?
>  — De acuerdo.
>  —<sup><sub>3</sub></sup>Si tienes un sueño, tienes que protegerlo. <sup><sub>4</sub></sup>Las personas que no pueden hacer una cosa, te van a querer decir que tú no puedes hacerla tampoco. <sup><sub>5</sub></sup>Si quieres algo, ve a por ello. Punto.
>
>  <sub>(225 characters)</sub>

Wanna win this game? Go get it!

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 61 characters

> —Que ni yo te pare.
>
> —Ya.
>
> —Los incapaces te dirán incapaz. ¡Cuida tu sueño y lógralo!

Comment: Bienvenido al juego, Carlos. No sé si fuiste tú el de los votos negativos a todas las otras respuestas, pero por si acaso: el concurso lo gana quien obtiene la mejor solución; los votos son algo tangencial e independiente.

Comment: Yo de hecho en estos juegos voto positivo a todo el mundo solo por participar ya que es de lo que se trata y no  importan tanto si la traducción gusta mas o menos, aun así los votos en preguntas wiki no afectan a la reputación.

Answer (score 4):

#### 109 caracteres

> —Que no te digan incapaz de algo. Ni yo. ¿Sí?
>   —Sí.
>   —Si es tu sueño, protégelo. Los incapaces te llamarán a ti lo mismo. Si lo quieres, va a por ello. Y ya.

Answer (score 3):

#### 64 caracteres

> —[Nadi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QCTBvh1), ni yo, te [helará](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K5znagI), ¿eh?
>   —Sí.
>   —Ve tras tu meta. Ningún [peal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SF5U7xU) te dirá peal. ¿[Ansías](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2kwLD5c)? Pues ¡[ea](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EIavMkp)!

Aclaraciones:

- El verbo *helar* se usa como sinónimo de *desalentar* ("quitar el ánimo"), como se ve en su tercera acepción.
- El sustantivo *peal* tiene una acepción coloquial como "persona inútil, torpe".
- La voz "ea" se usa "para denotar alguna resolución de la voluntad, o para animar, estimular o excitar".

Comment: @walen entiendo que "proteger tu sueño" es mantenerlo vivo, no olvidarse de él ni dejar que nadie lo estropee, y creo que "ir tras tu meta" respeta esa idea (se entiende que "sueño" es en este caso "objetivo ideal a conseguir", "aquello a lo que aspiras").

Answer (score 2):

#### 133 caracteres

> — Que nadie te diga qué no puedes hacer. Ni yo. ¿Vale?
> — Vale.
> — Protege tus sueños. Los que no son capaces de hacer algo
> te dirán que tú tampoco puedes. ¿Quieres algo? Búscalo. Y ya.

Answer (score 2):

## 73 caracteres

> —Que nadie ni yo te impida.
>
> —Sí.
>
> —Cuida tu sueño. La gente no quiere ser superada. Gana tu deseo ya.

Comment: Esto es como lo interpreté: Superar a alguien = hacer algo que él/ella todavía no ha hecho, algo más allá de su potencial. `"People can't do something themselves, they wanna tell you you can't do it."` = "People don't want you to be able to do what they can't" = "People don't want you to surpass them (to show them up, to succeed where they have failed and make their failure seem personal and not something unachievable in and of itself)" El foco es que la gente quiere seguir creyendo que algo es imposible, que nadie puede hacerlo, no que el problema es una falta de su propia trabajo/destreza.

Answer (score 2):

**68 caracteres**

> —Que no te desanimen, ni yo. ¿Vale?
>
> —Vale.
>
> —Tú ve a tu bola y pasa de agoreros. Tú a lo tuyo. Punto.